# Can we reference a YAML template from a Nuget package?

Tags: azure, templates, yaml, devops, nuget-package

I need to update a couple of pipelines to use the same logic and thought about using templates to split the common YAML steps.
All the projects share the same dependency with an in-house Nuget package that is used for deployment. My initial idea is to use that package to hold the template YAML and reference it on each project but when I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) I am not entirely sure this is supported.
To give you a better idea I'm going to exemplify with the same sample code on the documentation.
This would be our YAML in the Nuget package, to be inserted as a template reference on each project.

```
# File: templates/include-npm-steps.yml

steps:
- script: npm install
- script: yarn install
- script: npm run compile
```

This would be the YAML on each project that needed to consume the above YAML from the Nuget package.

```
# File: azure-pipelines.yml

jobs:
- job: Linux
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - template: templates/include-npm-steps.yml  # Template reference
- job: Windows
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - template: templates/include-npm-steps.yml  # Template reference
```

Probably at run time the pipeline checks for the referenced templates and won't run since they need to be restored first. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As suspected you cannot consume a YAML in a Nuget package but have to reference the YAML from a repo instead.